# syntax of comparison between two different things

Tags: c, operators

Following program gives error

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int a=10,b;
a>=5?b=100:b=200;
printf("\n%d",b);
}
```

the error is

```
ka1.c: In function ‘main’:
ka1.c:5: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

now if I replace the line

```
a>=5?b=100:b=200;
```

by

```
a>=5?b=100:(b=200);
```

and then compile then there is no error.
So I wanted to know what is wrong with

```
a>=5?b=100:b=200;
```

Comment: it is parsed as `(a>=5?b=100:b)=200;` in my opinion.

Comment: Operator priority? I guess the first case looks like this for the compiler: (a>=5?b=100:b)=200

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ternary operator (`?:`) has [*higher precedence*](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than the assignment operator (`=`).  So your original statement is interpreted as:

```
((a >= 5) ? (b = 100) : b) = 200;
```

Write it like this instead:

```
b = (a >= 5) ? 100 : 200;
```

This is idiomatic C.  (The brackets around the condition are not really necessary, but they aid readability.)

Answer (score 3):

You're using the ternary operator incorrectly. Both of your examples are wrong, even though one compiles. The expression evaluates to either the second or third sub-expression depending upon the truth value of the first.

So `a ? b : c` will be the same thing as `b` if `a` is true, or `c` if `a` is false.

The proper way of using this operator is to assign the result to a variable:

```
b = a>= 5 ? 100 : 200;
```

Comment: Why is the second example wrong? AFAIK it does the same thing as your example (although in a funny way).

Answer (score 1):

Because it tries to do: `(a>=5?b=100:b)=200`
But the thing in parentheses is not lvalue.

Comment: What do you mean by lvaue in paranthesis ?